# Java convert string to md5 and vise versa

Tags: java, md5

I have java three strings. let say example.

```
String test = "Hi, ";
String test1 = "this is ";
String test2 = "Java programming!";
```

I wanna combine those 3 string and change it to md5 format. How could I do? I use MessageDigest class for one string but i have no idea how to append 3 string before change to md5. And I wanna to change back md5 to string. Do i need external library.

Comment: You can't change back md5. It's not an encryption or an encoding - it's a *hash*. And just concatenate your strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MD5 is *not* a format, or an encryption algorithm.

MD5 is a **hash function**. That means, long text to short digest - for anything apart of very short inputs this transformation will obviously be lossy. In general, there is no going back from MD5 to plain text.

Comment: okay, then i have a question. I convert 3 strings to hash code. Could md5 produce duplicated characters for different strings? , if i convert one thousand of strings.

Comment: Yes, MD5 could produce same output for two different inputs, however chances of this happening for two (or even thousand) different random inputs are very small.

Answer (score 7):

Well reversing [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is not really feasible as -

- There can be more than one string giving the same MD5 (It is called a Hash collision.)
- It was designed to be hard to "reverse"

You would have seen lot of websites that provide reverse MD5 (as - [Option-1](http://md5.gromweb.com/) , [option-2](https://hashtoolkit.com/)).
These websites stores mapping of already used "**String and MD5**" (So if you use complex String they wont be able to deduce original one).

Moving back to Part - 1

[MessageDigest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) can be used to calculate MD5 of a given String in Java.
Its usage is fairly Simple -

```
        String testString="someText";
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(testString.getBytes());
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
        String hashtext = number.toString(16);
```

So in your problem it depends how you want to create hash -

Way 1 - As you asked we can have -

```
StringBuilder simpleString=new StringBuilder(test);
simpleString.append(test1);
simpleString.append(test2);
String testString=simpleString.toString();
```

And finally call the method defined above with input as - **testString**.

Way 2 - I will suggest you to use MD5 of MD5 to have secured checksum.

```
Output = MD5(MD5(test)+MD5(test1)+MD5(test2))
```

---

You can try creating a brute-force attack on a string of 3 characters. Assuming only English letters (A-Z, a-z) and numbers (0-9) are allowed, there are "only" 623 (238,328) combinations in this case.

Hope it helps. :)